# create folder(trusted), copy of MDE and shortcut

Tags: vbscript, registry

I have put together a script that I think will work, but the only code I know is some VBA.  Never tried to create a vbscript before, so my apologies if some errors are obvious, but pointers and corrections would be appreciated.

I am hoping I can give users in my company a link to this script and have them run it.  It will create a folder on their C Drive, make it a trusted location, copy a database frontend from the server into it and create a shortcut on their desktop linking to the new file. (I'm hoping the file will auto-update when a new version is made - I think that bit works though).

The code comes from various sources, including my own addled mind but would I need to download Visual Studio to test this?  Slightly concerned as it includes creating a registry key and I don't know how to stop the code if it all goes horribly wrong.  I don't even know how to break a loop (although I think I read somewhere you need to hit <kbd>Esc</kbd> twice).  Any tips on how to signify which sub is the main one to run on start would be good too.

EDIT : Code has been amended to my end result incase it is of use to others.  Please use with caution.  The 'update' vbs deletes the folder created on the local drive.

```
'FrontEnd Setup
call CreateTrustedFolder

'Const HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT = &H80000000 
Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001 
'Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002 
'Const HKEY_USERS = &H80000003 
'Const HKEY_CURRENT_CONFIG = &H80000005 

Dim lclFolder
Dim blnUpdate

Sub CreateTrustedFolder()
On error resume next
    Call RunAdmin
    Call FolderFileShortcut
    Call CreateReg
if err then
    MsgBox "The following error has occurred " & Err & " " & Err.Description
    exit Sub
end if
End Sub

'Run as Administrator
Sub RunAdmin()
On error resume next
If Not WScript.Arguments.Named.Exists("elevate") Then
  CreateObject("Shell.Application").ShellExecute WScript.FullName _
    , WScript.ScriptFullName & " /elevate", "", "runas", 1
  WScript.Quit
End If
if err then
    MsgBox "The following error has occurred " & Err & " " & Err.Description
    exit Sub
end if
End Sub

'Check if folder exists, add file and desktop shortcut
Sub FolderFileShortcut()
On error resume next
Dim oWS
Dim FSO
Dim svrFolder
Dim myShortcut
Dim strLocalDB
Dim strServerDB
Dim strUpdate
Dim strIcon
Dim objFile
Dim counter

Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    svrFolder = "\\192.168.1.2\DeptFolder\DatabaseFolder\Auto-Update"
    lclFolder = "C:\Program Files\Orrible Database"

If (FSO.FolderExists(lclFolder)) Then 
    oWS.run "icacls """ & lclFolder & """ /reset /grant:r Users:(W) /t" '/T required for existing folders
    FSO.DeleteFolder lclFolder
    blnUpdate = True
end if
If Not (FSO.FolderExists(svrFolder)) Then
    msgbox "Unable to connect to Location Server", vbCritical, "Installation Failed"
    WScript.Quit
End If
For Each objFile in FSO.Getfolder(svrFolder).Files
    if LCase(FSO.GetExtensionName(objFile.name)) = LCase("mde") then  
        counter = counter + 1
        strServerDB = FSO.GetFileName(objFile)
    end if
Next
If strServerDB = "" or counter <> 1 then
    msgbox "Unable to locate the Front End" & strServerDB & "-" & counter, vbCritical, "Installation Failed"
    wScript.Quit
end if

strLocalDB = "Co Database.mde"
strUpdate = "DB_UpdateCheck.vbs"
strIcon = "Frontend Update.ico"
FSO.CreateFolder(lclFolder)
oWS.run "icacls """ & lclFolder & """ /grant Users:(OI)(CI)F /t" '/T required for existing folders
FSO.CopyFile svrFolder & "\" & strUpdate, lclFolder & "\" & strUpdate, True
FSO.CopyFile svrFolder & "\" & strServerDB, lclFolder & "\" & strLocalDB, True
FSO.CopyFile svrFolder & "\" & strIcon, lclFolder & "\" & strIcon, True 

strDesktop = oWS.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
set myShortcut = oWS.CreateShortcut(strDesktop + "\New Database.lnk")
myShortcut.TargetPath = lclFolder & "\" & strUpdate 
myShortcut.WindowStyle = 1
myShortcut.IconLocation = lclFolder & "\" & strIcon
myShortcut.WorkingDirectory = strDesktop
myShortcut.Save
if err then
MsgBox "The following error has occurred " & Err & " " & Err.Description
exit Sub
end if
End Sub


Sub CreateReg()
On error resume next
Dim objRegistry         'registry object
Dim strDescription      'Description of the Trusted Location
Dim strParentKey        'Registry location of Application
Dim strNewKey           'strParentKey and myFolder
Dim oWS                 'WSH shell object

strDescription = "DB Folder"
strParentKey = "Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Access\Security\Trusted Locations"
strNewKey = strParentKey & "\" & strDescription & "\"

Set objRegistry = GetObject("winmgmts:\\.\root\default:StdRegProv")     
'objRegistry.GetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strParentKey & "\" & strDescription 
If Not objRegistry.EnumKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strNewKey) = 0 then '0=true
    objRegistry.CreateKey HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strNewKey
    objRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strNewKey, "Path", lclFolder
    objRegistry.SetStringValue HKEY_CURRENT_USER, strNewKey, "Description", strDescription
End if
If not blnUpdate = True then
    msgbox "The Database is now available from your desktop", vbInformation, "Setup Complete"
Else
    msgbox "The update is now complete."
End if
if err then
    MsgBox "The following error has occurred " & Err & " " & Err.Description
    exit Sub
end if
End Sub
```

There is also a separate Update vbs which is what runs when the link is clicked.  This checks to see if the 'created date' of the database on the server is newer than that on the local drive.  The new DB name MUST NOT be the same as the one it is replacing.  It might run a little fast, but this is as far as I have taken this.

```
Call CheckForUpdate

Sub CheckForUpdate()
On Error Resume Next
    Dim FSO
    Dim oWS
    Dim svrFolder
    Dim lclFolder
    Dim svrFail
    Dim strLocalDB
    Dim strServerDB
    Dim lclDate
    Dim svrDate
    Dim strFileName
    Dim intDBcount
    Dim fCheck

    Set oWS = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Set FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    svrFolder = "\\192.168.1.2\DeptFolder\DatabaseFolder\Auto-Update"
    lclFolder = "C:\Program Files\Orrible Database"
    strLocalDB = "Co Database.mde"

    If Not (FSO.FolderExists(svrFolder)) Then
        msgbox "Unable to connect to Location Server", vbCritical, "Update Check Failed"
        svrFail = True
    End If
    If Not svrFail = True Then 
        For Each fCheck in FSO.GetFolder(svrFolder).Files
            If Ucase(Right(fCheck.Name, 3))  = "MDE" Then
                intDBcount = intDBcount + 1
                strServerDB = fCheck.name
            End If
        Next
        If Not intDBcount = 1 Then
            MsgBox "Please inform the Administrator that there is a problem with the Automated Update System.", _
              vbCritical, "Update Failed (" & intDBcount & ")"
              svrFail = True 'not quit - need to see if old version available
        End If
    End If
    If Not (FSO.FolderExists(lclFolder)) Then 
        If svrFail = True Then 'If no lcl folder or server
            If Not intDBcount = 1 then WScript.Quit
            msgbox "You are unable to use the Database." & vbcrlf & _
              "Please try again when you have access to the Location Server.", _
              vbcritical, "Database Not Installed"
              WScript.Quit
        Else 'If no lclfolder, get it from svr
            'Do normal initial install
            oWS.Run svrFolder & "\" & "DB_Install.vbs", 1, True
            WScript.Quit
        End If
    Else
        If svrFail = True Then 'If lcl folder, but no svr
            'open db
            oWS.Run CHR(34) & lclFolder & "\" & strLocalDB & CHR(34)
            WScript.Quit
        Else 'If lcl folder and svr access, check for update.
            lclDate = fso.getfile(lclFolder & "\" & strLocalDB).DateCreated
            svrDate = fso.getfile(svrFolder & "\" & strServerDB).DateCreated
            If lclDate < svrDate Then 'Update available
                intMsg = MsgBox("An update is available - Do you wish to update now?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Update Found")
                If intMsg = vbYes Then
                    oWS.Run svrFolder & "\" & "DB_Install.vbs", 1, True ',1,true should pause the code until install closes
                    oWS.Run CHR(34) & lclFolder & "\" & strLocalDB & CHR(34)
                    WScript.Quit
                Else
                    oWS.Run CHR(34) & lclFolder & "\" & strLocalDB & CHR(34)
                    WScript.Quit
                End If
            Else
                oWS.Run CHR(34) & lclFolder & "\" & strLocalDB & CHR(34)
                WScript.Quit
            End If
        End If
    End If
If err Then
    MsgBox "The following error has occurred " & Err & " " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you want a code review? SO is not the right place for that.

Comment: Totally understood.  If you could give me some pointers as to the basics it would be appreciated - what software would I be able to test this in?  Are there any forums or sites you would suggest that may review the code or give me pointers on the code as a novice?

Comment: I compiled a list of the main [differences between VBScript and VBA](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml) a while ago. Maybe that'll get you started.